# External JSON from API into array?

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

Ok, I have a JSON file from a website API that I need to re-arrange so the data can be read by Highcharts.  I do not know how to proceed.  I have a URL and from reading the docs on highcharts website, I need to re-format the data to be used correctly, so, how should I proceed?

Should I set up a php file that loads the JSON file, then use javascript to pick out what I want?  If so, how would I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example of the JSON data

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1382918400,
    "localTimestamp": 1382918400,
    "issueTimestamp": 1382918400,
    "fadedRating": 4,
    "solidRating": 0,
    "swell": {
      "minBreakingHeight": 5,
      "absMinBreakingHeight": 4.508,
      "maxBreakingHeight": 7,
      "absMaxBreakingHeight": 7.049,
      "unit": "ft",
      "components": {
        "combined": {
          "height": 18,
          "period": 10,
          "direction": 37.25,
          "compassDirection": "SW"
        },
        "primary": {
          "height": 18,
          "period": 10,
          "direction": 47.09,
          "compassDirection": "SW"
        }
      }
    },
    "wind": {
      "speed": 15,
      "direction": 79,
      "compassDirection": "W",
      "chill": 54,
      "gusts": 29,
      "unit": "mph"
    },
    "condition": {
      "pressure": 986,
      "temperature": 59,
      "weather": "23",
      "unitPressure": "mb",
      "unit": "f"
    },
    "charts": {
      "swell": "http://chart-1.msw.ms/wave/750/1-1382918400-1.gif",
      "period": "http://chart-1.msw.ms/wave/750/1-1382918400-2.gif",
      "wind": "http://chart-1.msw.ms/gfs/750/1-1382918400-4.gif",
      "pressure": "http://chart-1.msw.ms/gfs/750/1-1382918400-3.gif",
      "sst": "http://chart-1.msw.ms/sst/750/1-1382918400-10.gif"
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give samples of the JSON data that you have, and what you need it transformed into, along with the code you've tried to achieve your goal.

Comment: Highcharts has an article about it [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json) but from what it sounds like you have the right idea. Just use Javascript to pick out what you need and feed it into Highcharts.

Comment: @AndrewCooper I've added some of the data to the post..  Thx for the help!

Comment: @aug I read that article earlier and thought that if I could just get the data loaded into another file then I could grab what I need from it with that piece of code.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON i.e in javascript, by prepareing correct structure

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
```

and use it like

```
series: customSeries
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use PHP for parsing the JSON file, you can directly doing it in JavaScript.

You can either doing it by yourself or using a library like http://underscorejs.org/ or even better http://lodash.com/.

What are exactly your JSON input and the output which can be read by Hightchart ?